# Combining for loop output

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, netcdf, cbind

I want to write a loop that extracts a table from a three dimensional array and sequentially write it to a data frame as a column.

The code I have so far is

```
library(ncdf4)

test <- nc_open("NorESM_TREFHT_cont_mem1-60_2006-2099.nc")
temp <- ncvar_get(test, "TREFHT", count = c(144,96,60,1))
drop(temp)
lat<- ncvar_get(test, "lat")
lon <- ncvar_get(test,"lon")
lonlat <- expand.grid(lon, lat)
for (n in 1:60) {
member <- array(temp[1:144,1:96,n])
ensemble <- as.vector(member)
h <- data.frame(cbind(lonlat, ensemble[n]))
}
```

Currently the code works without the loop (for n = 1,2 etc.)
but only combines the last run in the for loop output for n=1:60

Comment: I guess you have functions there that are not primitive to R. Can you tell us the package where they come from please?

Comment: I am working with netCDF4 files using the package **ncdf4**

Comment: Can you also create an example for what test would look like? I can't recreate your problem because I don't have access to that .nc file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `h` isn't used yet; in other words useless. You probably want to add in each step of `n` the variable `ensemble` to your `lonlat` data. So your code should be `lonlat <- data.frame(cbind(lonlat, ensemble[n]))`.

Comment: This solution worked perfectly. I was wondering if you could expand on h being useless. I am a new r user and I dont fully understand some of the dynamics of objects in r.

Comment: @Dylan each time the `for loop` executes it is 're-assigning' the object `h`. Therefore it is 'writing' over itself, hence why you are left with just the last output `n = 60`